# Restoring warning state with #pragma warning(pop) fails in release (not debug) when including afxwin.h in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I am setting warning level on a project to 4 and realized that `#pragma warning(pop)` seems to fail in release builds when including afxwin.h

Here is a reproducer code:

```
#pragma warning(push, 4)

void boo1()
{
    auto x = 43;

}

#pragma warning(push)

#define _AFXDLL
#include <afxwin.h>

#pragma warning(pop)

void boo2()
{
    auto x = 43;

}
```

In debug I get two messages

> warning C4189: 'x' : local variable is initialized but not referenced

one for each `boo` function.
How ever if I switch to release I get only one, the first one.

```
#include <afxwin.h>
```

behaves weird and I wonder what happen. It seems that VS 2013 does not have this behaviour, except when I retarget the VS2013 solution to use v110 Visual Studio 2012 platform toolset.

Did I found an obscure compiler bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick google search shows that this issue was [reported](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/789970) for visual studio 2012 and fixed in 2013. Quote from ticket:

> We found a very likely cause of this problem in afxwin2.inl, lines 784 - 791:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 6001 6054)
 _AFXWIN_INLINE int CListBox::GetText(_In_ int nIndex, _Pre_notnull_ _Post_z_ LPTSTR lpszBuffer) const
{ 
 ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); 
 return (int)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, LB_GETTEXT, nIndex, LPARAM)lpszBuffer); 
}
#pragma warning(push)
```

> The second push pragma on line 791 must be a pop statement instead.